# android | How to check if state is play or pause of iamgeButton

Tags: java, android, button, android-view, android-imagebutton

I am using this [github package android-material-play-pause-view](https://github.com/OHoussein/android-material-play-pause-view) to implement an animated play pause button in my application. But I cannot figure how to check what is currently selected (play or pause).

Here is the xml:

```
    <com.ohoussein.playpause.PlayPauseView
        android:id="@+id/linuxPlayPause"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerVersion"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        app:fill_color="#ffff"
        app:pause_bg="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:play_bg="@color/colorAccent"
        />
```

I cannot see any getter methods to retrieve this information and the only thing described in the `README` seems to be `.toggle()` I also tried going through the source and found no clue.
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use boolean isPlay.

```
boolean isPlay = false;
PlayPauseView view = (PlayPauseView) findViewById(R.id.play_pause_view);
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isPlay = !isPlay;
                view.toggle();
            }
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide some explanation? How can I determine if the button is in pause or play state?

Comment: see this https://github.com/OHoussein/android-material-play-pause-view/blob/master/playpauseview/src/main/java/com/ohoussein/playpause/PlayPauseView.java and line 42 private final PlayPauseDrawable mDrawable;   mDrawable.isPlay()

Comment: isPlay = true means icon play show now and isPlay = false means icon pause show

Comment: isPlay should be false to start with because the default is set to pause, you code when isPlay = true, it is in pause state, and when isPlay= false, it is in play state.

Comment: Okay But I want to execute some code when the button is play and some other code when the button is pause. How can I do that using this?

Comment: you could do if(isPlay) {...}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the library as it is, you could compare the background color with getColor since your app:pause_bg app:play_bg are different.

if yourview.getColor() is @color/colorPrimary, it is in pause state

else if yourview.getColor() is @color/colorAccent, it is in play state

```
if(isPlay(yourPlayPauseView)){
    //...
}:
```

after adding the following function:

```
private boolean isPlay(PlayPauseView yourview) {
    return yourview.getColor() == getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
}
```

otherwise, you could add in PlayPauseView.java the following code:

```
private int getPlay() {
    return mDrawable.isPlay();
}
```

and call yourview.getPlay() to return true(play) or false(pause).

Comment: I have included the package from build.gradle how can I edit PlayPauseView.java I don't see it anywhere?

Comment: see my edit which is easier to do.
otherwise, follow this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828591/unable-to-edit-external-library-files-showing-as-locked-in-android-studio